# Extracting the id in all these cases

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I always extract the number 11 in all these cases.

```
id="section-11" 
id="test-11"
id="something-11"
```

I do `$(this).attr('id');` then what do I do next?

Comment: I've been trying to get a jsperf.com test running with all of these different examples to see which one is faster.  No luck though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many ways to achieve that, one way is to use `.split()` like:

```
var id = "section-11";

var number = id.split(/-/)[ 1 ];

alert( number );  // 11
```

Comment: +1 Thank the lord! A SO contributor employing the sane way to perform a simple task with strings.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(this).attr('id').match(/\d+/)[0]
```

This will pull the first numeric match.

Comment: Why do people always jump straight to the overkill regex engine?

Comment: I wasn't aware regex was overkill.  Please share.

Comment: @John: If all you need is to split a string on a delimiter, loading up the regex engine and doing a full parse of the string is clearly overkill. I'm not really sure in what way you want me to "share"?

Comment: @Tomalak By "sharing" I wouldn't mind a factual explanation.  Using terms such as "loading up", "full parse" shows loads of bias.  Have you done speed tests?  Splitting a string on a delimiter which may or may not be there is not always dependable.  "something11", "section11", "something-else-11", etc.

Comment: Incase anyone is wondering, I did crunch the numbers - iterated each operation 1,000,000 times - .split('-') ran in ~800ms, .split(/-/) ran in ~980ms, and .match(/\d+/) ran in ~1600ms (per million).  So Tomalak would be correct that using .split() is almost twice as fast as .match().  Furthermore, using a string instead of a regex expression with split is even quicker.  Personally, I prefer match because regex is more powerful.  String manipulation is great too if you can be 100% assured that the string you are parsing will always be in a certain format.

Comment: @JohnStrickler: I don't see the bias. Fact: you have to load the regex engine. Fact: you have to do a full parse of the input, and of each character within each possible submatch. For a simple string split all you have to do is iterate through the string, once, character-by-character, sticking characters in blocks as you go and jumping to a new block whenever you see a `-`. That's it. _You don't need "speed tests" to make rational deductions_, and these basic empirical tests tell you little about the _complexity_ of an algorithm (which is often the most important thing).

Comment: @JohnStrickler: What a non-sensical thing to say. If I'm driving my car at 60mph, that says _nothing_ about the _limits_ of its capabilities. And this is **incredibly important** when talking about computer algorithms. You either perform far more thorough tests and hope that you didn't miss one, or you use the fool-proof method of looking up the facts specified by the designer. And if the designer got the facts wrong, then that's his fault and another matter entirely.

Comment: So I'm gathering that you don't like using regular expressions?

Comment: @JohnStrickler: You're leaping to yet more conclusions. I love regular expressions; they are powerful and awesome and great. I just wouldn't dream of using them for a piddly little string manipulation like this! **Use the right tool for the job.**

Comment: I've clearly known what you are saying all along, you think I'm using a nuclear warhead instead of a bullet.  I just think you're wrong.

Comment: @JohnStrickler: "So I'm gathering that you don't like using regular expressions" indicates that you did *not* know what I have been saying. Good luck with your programming!

Comment: Join a debate team.  You need an outlet for your aggression.

Comment: @JohnStrickler: Stack Overflow is the outlet for my aggression ;)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that those last two digits are going to be the only numbers in the id, here's a regex replace to do it:

```
var id = 'something-11';
var num = id.replace(/\D/g,'');

alert(num);
```

The above deletes all non-numeric characters from the string.

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/NL4qz/1/)

Comment: /\D/g - global non-digit replace.

Answer (score 0):

```
var id = parseInt($(this).attr('id).substring($(this).attr('id').lastIndexOf('-')+1));
```

The `.split()` example above also works, but you'll need to grab the highest index in the array, in case you name an id with more than 1 dash: sub-section-11

Answer (score 0):

you can split the string to an array by "-", then you will get the id from the second place of the array.